# A working way of authenticating and authorising Vuejs apps (with a Laravel Backend)?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am making a VueJS app with a Laravel backend. I see Laravel has Passport which is used to authenticate/authorize APIs. (Sincerely I have not yet succeeded in integrating Passport. I have not understood where the starting point is. Will post that question separately).

I have done a lot of searching and still have not found the best/easiest way of doing authentication and authorization, and also interface control depending on permission. (I know "best" is subjective but basically means a method that is easy to integrate, understand and use).

Anyone who has been there and used one that worked really well?

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/create-an-app-in-vuejs-2/

Comment: Thanks @fatman. Though I ended up using a JWT approach rather than the OAuth route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io) for my web and mobile apps. It's simpler to set up than Oauth and is a better fit for many applications.

Basically, the user sends a POST request containing their authentication details to the appropriate endpoint and receives a token in response. The user can then include that token in the Authorization header of future requests to authenticate them.

The token also includes a timestamp for when it expires, and it can be decoded on the client side so that an application can refresh the token before it expires.

There's an excellent [implementation of JWT for Laravel](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) which I use all the time and can highly recommend. There are also client-side libraries for handling JWT with pretty much every framework under the sun.

Comment: Ended up following a JWT approach as you say. It is way easier to figure around and use than Oauth. Marked yours as the answer, but for anyone else I will post a separate answer about what I exactly did.

Answer (score 0):

@MatthewDaly, I followed your recommendation and I stumbled on a VueJs-Laravel JWT implementation here: http://jimfrenette.com/2016/11/laravel-vuejs2-jwt-auth/

I followed through the Tutorial and was able to make it work for my case. (Caveat: The post is slightly old (using Laravel 5.2), but with good understanding of Vue and Laravel, you can be able to follow and implement it easily).